# Hosting multiple website on my EC2 instance is not working properly

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to host multiple website on Amazon Ec2 linux, but it is only show the home dashboard website. I try as following virtual host configuration in httpd.conf too.

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/SITE-1"
ServerName www.myexample1.com

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/SITE-2"
ServerName www.myexample2.com

If i put like http://10.123.12.12/SITE-1 and http://10.123.12.12/SITE-2 it's getting the right page

But if i given with the DNS name the default page is only loading up, the two different site is not loading up

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your document root is still being set to `/var/www/html` and you may not have the proper VirtualHost containers.  Try something like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/SITE-1"
  ServerName www.myexample1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/SITE-2" 
  ServerName www.myexample2.com
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/html/SITE-1">
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/SITE-2">
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

If you need to do SSL, you'll need to include port 443 and some other options.